# Trying to store answers in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that sends a score to a text file 
could you help here is my code

```
if cn == "1":
    fi = open("class1.txt","w")
    fi.write("\n" + str(name) + ":" + str(score))
    fi.close ()
```

Comment: And this isn't working... how?

Comment: I don't know how it wont write any thing in the text file @MarcB

Comment: you must specify what you have, what you need and what is not working... try to rewrite your question to fit this needs

Comment: ok it is a maths quiz and I am trying to send each persons score to a text file depending on which class they are in 1,2,3 @AresDraguna

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
while questionNo == 10 and score >= 0:
    if schClass == '1':
     inFile = open("scores1.txt", 'a')
     inFile.write("\n" + name + " : " + str(score))
     inFile.close()
     score = -1
    elif schClass == '2':
     inFile = open("scores2.txt", 'a')
     inFile.write("\n" + name + " : " + str(score))
     inFile.close()
     score = -1
    elif schClass == '3':
     inFile = open("scores3.txt", 'a')
     inFile.write("\n" + name + " : " + str(score))
     inFile.close()
     score = -1
```